# Index of DataTable Row on which selectOneMenu Item is selected

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-datatable

I am trying to Implement a editable DataTable, with selectOneMenu in one of the columns.
How to get the selected Dropdown value along with its corresponding rowkeyId.
The approach I was following is to trigger itemSelect ajax event get the selected value and store it in the backend but couldn't figure out hot get its corresponding rowkeyId.

Comment: Please share code of what you (attempt) to do. Sounds like an https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.